# Jquery pop up not working properly

Tags: jquery

So I am new to Jquery and I am trying to have a pop up form. The goal is that when the user clicks "Create New User" a form will pop up and they can fill out the information there. I am having trouble. I feel as if I have everything set up correctly, but it is still not working.

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html class="no-js"  lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

            <title>Ocean Services</title>
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

            <title>Bliss Salon</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
            <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
              <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
              <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>


            <script>
              $(function() {
              var name = $( "#name" ),
              email = $( "#email" ),
              password = $( "#password" ),
              allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
              tips = $( ".validateTips" );
              function updateTips( t ) {
              tips
              .text( t )
              .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
              setTimeout(function() {
              tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
              }, 500 );
              }
              function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
              if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
              o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
              updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
              min + " and " + max + "." );
              return false;
              } else {
              return true;
              }
              }
              function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
              if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
              o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
              updateTips( n );
              return false;
              } else {
              return true;
              }
              }
              $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: 300,
              width: 350,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
              "Create an account": function() {
              var bValid = true;
              allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
              bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
              // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
              bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
              if ( bValid ) {
              $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
              "</tr>" );
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
              },
              Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
              },
              close: function() {
              allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
              }
              });
              $( "#create-user" )
              .button()
              .click(function() {
              $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
              });
              });
              </script>
          </head>
          <body>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="large-6 columns">
                  <h1><img class="logo" src="images/trans_logo.png" /></h1>
              </div>
              <div class="large-12 columns">
                  <ul class="right button-group">

                      <li><a href="#" class="nav" >Log-In</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="nav">Register</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>

          <!-- End Header and Nav -->

          <!-- First Band (Slider) -->

          <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
                  <div data-orbit id="slider">
                      <a href="#"> <img src="images/image1.jpeg" /></a>
                      <img src="images/image2.jpeg" />
                  </div>

                  <hr />
              </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Three-up Content Blocks -->

          <div class="row">
              <div class="large-6 columns">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=[img]" />
                  <h4>This is a content section.</h4>
                  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet nulla ham qui sint exercitation eiusmod commodo, chuck duis velit. Aute in reprehenderit, dolore aliqua non est magna in labore pig pork biltong. Eiusmod swine spare ribs reprehenderit culpa. Boudin aliqua adipisicing rump corned beef.</p>
              </div>


              <div class="large-6 columns">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=[img]" />
                  <h4>This is a content section.</h4>
                  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet nulla ham qui sint exercitation eiusmod commodo, chuck duis velit. Aute in reprehenderit, dolore aliqua non est magna in labore pig pork biltong. Eiusmod swine spare ribs reprehenderit culpa. Boudin aliqua adipisicing rump corned beef.</p>
                  <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
              </div>

          </div>




          <!-- Footer -->

          <footer class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
                  <hr />
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="large-6 columns">
                          <p>© Copyright Bliss Salon. All Rights Reserved.</p>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </footer>


            <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
            <script>
              $(document).foundation({
                     orbit: {
                         timer_speed:4500,
                         timer: true,
                         bullets:false,
                         animation:'fade',
                         animation_speed: 1500


                     }


              });
            </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you narrow your code down to only the relevant sections?

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8992/)

You forgot your dialog div in your html:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

After you put in your `div with id dialog-form` in your html, it should work.